# Using Thymeleaf to create links that open in a new window/tab

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

In basic HTML, a link can have the `target="_blank"` property to force it to open in a new window or tab. But if when I put that in an `<a href>` tag that also includes a `th:href` for Thymeleaf, Thymeleaf overwrites the whole tag and wipes out my `target="_blank`.

I've considered the brute force method of adding `target="_blank"` to every link as it is stored in my database so that it is already part of the link when Thymeleaf writes it out. But I would prefer a way to have Thymeleaf write the `target="_blank"` property as it is writing the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Try `th:target="_blank"` instead

Comment: Thanks @conscells. I'll try that!

Comment: And the `th:target="_blank"` works!

Comment: @MrLister Done.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thymeleaf overwrites the `a` tag. Use `th:target="_blank"`.

Comment: Full example `<a th:href="@{https://MY-URL}" th:target="_blank">`